# Creating Document Library View Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, permissions, view

I working with SP2013 and do not have access to SP Designer.

I need assistance with the following: 
I want to create a document library.

The objective is to have:
 
1. view that allows users with full permissions to view the library.
2. to have other users ONLY view their designated list.

**UPDATE**: After research... is this the best way to go about it? 
1.  Create a web part page.  Add a links web part that connects to the original document library. (Only thing is that I do not know how to connect web parts to document libraries)
2. The links on web part page will connect to the users designated page that only they can see.  This is a an idea, however, I am not sure if this can be done or not.

How would I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy this, you'd want to go into the DOcument library settings and set the Item Level Permissions so that users have access to their own files. Anyone listed with full control permissions on the library will be able to see everything.

Then you create a view where there is a filter where the created by person is equal to [Me].

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following this. There does not seem to be any permission setting that allows for "Edit my own documents". Or am I giving everyone full control, then using the filter so that they can only see their own documents?